# Plugin to redirect all 404 pages to a specific page

Tags: plugins

I want to redirect all 404 pages to a specific page (not the homepage).

Is there any plugin that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a 404.php template file in the themes folder. All 404 redirects should be using this template file from then onwards.

Comment: I need it to be a 301 redirect

Comment: Use the PHP `header` method to create 301 redirect from the 404.php.